# Trouble sending JavaScript into <input type="date"> calendar

Tags: javascript, selenium, python-behave

**Goal:** Attempting to automate a  calendar on Chrome using Selenium(Python + behave).

**The issue:** The date is only being set when actually clicked through the calendar. Passing a value via JavaScript is not working.

**Note:** According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) the inputs should allow users to send input in with keys by default but that doesn't even work. It does not accept keyboard input at all.

---

*Problem Walkthrough*

- This is the original input fields. The div class they are contained in is inside a #shadow-root
  (open):

[image]

- Ignoring the Python. I will try and change the values with some simple JavaScript in the Chrome Dev Tools console:

```
    x = document.querySelector("#class > something").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > input[type=date]:nth-child(5)") #Select input for From Date
    x = "2022-05-12"
    y = document.querySelector("#class > something").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > input[type=date]:nth-child(5)") #Select input for To Date
    y = "2022-06-12"
```

- After sending in the new values and clicking search. It does not recognize the values as being entered:

[image]

- However, when manually selected through the calendar:

[image]

- The dates are accepted and as inputs:

[image]

---

The HTML for the calendar is:

```
<input type="date" min="2022-01-01" max="2022-07-19">
```

Clearly. The JavaScript alone does not seem to be enough. If you use the same method above on [this calendar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#setting_maximum_and_minimum_dates) it will work. However, on the calendar I am attempting this JS method will not work for some reason. Also, I cannot get Selenium to click and open the calendar on its own for some odd reason.

Comment: Without access to the real calendar I found very difficult try to help you, if possible please provide a minimum reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: Try updating and/or adding the "value" attribute.  (using execute_script() JS method) When you click search it should send that as the value.  Ex: <input type="date" value="2022-07-19">

Comment: @pcalkins Unfortunately I have tried exactly this. However, same result with it only moving being the search screen and accepting the input if manually selected with the calendar .

Comment: @ManuelMB Sadly its a local site. The Mozilla docs I linked have some examples. However, the one I am attempting to do it on seems to be an edge case.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium okay. Please let me prepare the HTML then I will update the question. Would you like the HTML for the entire calendar so you can replicate the bug?

Comment: Yes, the calendar element including the parent of the **shadowRoot** element.

Comment: You probably need to dispatch a change event to the input.

Comment: @pguardiario Your right! That worked. Thank you. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript```let element = document.getElementById(id);
element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));```

Comment: @undetectedSelenium pguardiario was able to answer it before I got the chance to send HTML. Thank you so much for your replies though

Comment: @Crunchy Could you provide the full code that you finally used instead of:

x = document.querySelector("#class > something").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > input[type=date]:nth-child(5)") #Select input for From Date
    x = "2022-05-12"
    y = document.querySelector("#class > something").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > input[type=date]:nth-child(5)") #Select input for To Date
    y = "2022-06-12"

Comment: @ManuelMB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript ```let element = document.getElementById(id);
element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); ``` See the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Manually trigger the event ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript))

```
let element = document.getElementById(id);
element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); // or whatever the event type might be
```

[dispatchEvent() Documentatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

[Event() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)